# SaltStack: Do "etckeeper init" if /etc/.git is not there

Tags: saltstack, etckeeper

I want to deploy the tool [etckeeper](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) via SaltStack.

Installating the RPM/DPKG is easy.

Next step is to call `etckeeper init` after the installation.

My current idea is this pseudo-code:

> execute `etckeeper init` if `/etc/.git` does not exist

I read the docs for [file.exists](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.exists), but this does not help me.

How to solve this with SaltStack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "creates" argument to cmd.run, which tells saltstack to avoid running a command if a files already exists:

```
etckeeper_init:
  cmd.run:
    - name: etckeeper init
    - creates: /etc/.git
```

Comment: Wow, that's cool. I did not know this before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. Other solutions are welcome!

```
etckeeper:
  pkg.installed

{%- if not salt['file.directory_exists' ]('/etc/.git') %}
init_etckeeper:
  cmd.run:
    - name: etckeeper init

initial_commit_etckeeper:
  cmd.run:
    - name: etckeeper commit -m "initial commit"
{%- endif %}
```